# Text doesn't match the file text even though it does Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make it so that it can detect unsaved changes in my notepad application. There are no errors but the problem is that it thinks that the text always isn't equivalent to the file even though it is the same? I can't seem to figure out why this is and it is bugging me so much XD. I have some screenshots to demonstrate the issue.

```
import tkinter
import platform
import sys
import os
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import tkinter.font as fonttext
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading

class Intervala(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback, event, interval: int):
        self.callback = callback
        self.event = event
        self.interval = interval
        super(Intervala, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        while not self.event.wait(self.interval):
            self.callback()

class Notepad:

    __defversion = '0.0.0.2'

    __root = Tk()

    __thisWidth = 300
    __thisHeight = 300
    __thisTextArea = Text(__root)
    __thisMenuBar = Menu(__root)
    __thisFileMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisEditMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisHelpMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)

    __thisScrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(__thisTextArea)
    __file = None

    event = threading.Event()

    #If it is saved
    __bool2 = False
    
    def __saveFile(self):

        if self.__file == None:
            self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                            defaultextension=".txt",
                                            filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                       ("Text Documents", "*.txt"),
                                                       ("JavaScript Documents", "*.js")])

            self.__bool2 = True

            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:
                file = open(self.__file, "w")
                file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
                file.close()
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")

        else:
            file = open(self.__file, "w")
            file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
            file.close()
    
    def __saveFile1(self, event):

        if self.__file == None:
            self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                            defaultextension=".txt",
                                            filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                       ("Text Documents", "*.txt"),
                                                       ("JavaScript Documents", "*.js")])
            self.__bool2 = True

            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:
                file = open(self.__file, "w")
                file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
                file.close()
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")

        else:
            file = open(self.__file, "w")
            file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
            file.close()

    def __quitApplication(self):
        a = askyesno('Exit', "Are you sure you want to exit Notepad?")
        if a:
            self.__root.destroy()
        else:
            return showinfo('Exit', "Sucessfully cancelled closing the program")

    def __quitApplication1(self, event):
        a = askyesno('Exit', "Are you sure you want to exit Notepad?")
        if a:
            self.__root.destroy()
            self.event.set()
        else:
            return showinfo('Exit', "Sucessfully cancelled closing the program")

    def __version(self):
        showinfo('Notepad', f'{self.__defversion} Windows distribution\nMac distribution also available.')

    def __showAbout(self):
        showinfo("Notepad", "Notepad Ultimate is a Notepad text editor made by Notepad Ul. Notepad Ul. is made by Queryzi")

    def __openFile(self):
        try:
            self.__file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt",
                                      filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                 ("Text Documents", "*.txt"),
                                                 ("JavaScript Documents", "*.js")])
            self.__bool2 = True

            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")
                self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0, END)

                file = open(self.__file, "r")

                self.__thisTextArea.insert(1.0, file.read())

                file.close()
        except:
                showerror("Invalid codec for file", "Recieved a file that is not a text type and cannot decode.")
                self.__root.destroy()
    
    def __openFile1(self, event):
        try:
            self.__file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt",
                                      filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                 ("Text Documents", "*.txt"),
                                                 ("JavaScript Documents", "*.js")])

            self.__bool2 = True

            if self.__file == "":
                self.__file = None
            else:

            # Try to open the file
            # set the window title
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")
                self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0, END)

                file = open(self.__file, "r")

                self.__thisTextArea.insert(1.0, file.read())

                file.close()
        except:
                showerror("Invalid codec for file", "Recieved a file that is not a text type and cannot decode.")
                self.__root.destroy()

    def __newFile(self):
        self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
        self.__file = None
        self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0, END)
    
    def __newFile1(self, event):
        self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
        self.__file = None
        self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0, END)

    def __cut(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Cut>>")

    def __copy(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Copy>>")

    def __paste(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.event_generate("<<Paste>>")

    def __delete(self):
        self.__thisTextArea.delete(1.0, END)
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
             
        try:
            self.__root.wm_iconbitmap("Notepad.ico")
        except:
            pass

        try:
            self.__thisWidth = kwargs['width']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            self.__thisHeight = kwargs['height']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad")

        screenWidth = self.__root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenHeight = self.__root.winfo_screenheight()

        left = (screenWidth / 2) - (self.__thisWidth / 2)

        top = (screenHeight / 2) - (self.__thisHeight / 2)

        self.__root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.__thisWidth,
                                              self.__thisHeight,
                                              left, top))

        interval = Intervala(self.__check, self.event, 2)
        interval.start()

        self.__root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.__root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.__thisTextArea.grid(sticky=N + E + S + W)


        self.__root.bind('<Control-n>', self.__newFile1)

        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="New",
                                        command=self.__newFile, accelerator="Ctrl+N")

        '''self.__thisTextMenu.add_command(label="Size",
                                        command=self.__size)

        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Options",
                                        menu=self.__thisTextMenu)'''



        self.__root.bind('<Control-o>', self.__openFile1)

        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Open",
                                        command=self.__openFile, accelerator="Ctrl+O")


        self.__root.bind('<Control-s>', self.__saveFile1)

        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Save",
                                        command=self.__saveFile, accelerator="Ctrl+S")

        self.__thisFileMenu.add_separator()
        self.__root.bind('<Control-e>', self.__quitApplication1)
        self.__thisFileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",
                                        command=self.__quitApplication, accelerator="Ctrl+E")
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="File",
                                       menu=self.__thisFileMenu)

        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Cut",
                                        command=self.__cut, accelerator="Ctrl+X")

        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Copy",
                                        command=self.__copy, accelerator="Ctrl+C")

        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Paste",
                                        command=self.__paste, accelerator="Ctrl+V")
        self.__thisEditMenu.add_command(label="Delete",
                                        command=self.__delete)

        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Edit",
                                       menu=self.__thisEditMenu)

        self.__thisHelpMenu.add_command(label="About Notepad",
                                        command=self.__showAbout)
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Help",
                                       menu=self.__thisHelpMenu)

        self.__thisHelpMenu.add_separator()
        self.__thisHelpMenu.add_command(label='Version', command=self.__version)

        self.__root.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar)

        self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTextArea.yview)
        self.__thisTextArea.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set)
        self.__root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__exit)

    def __check(self):
        if self.__file == None:
            if self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END) == "":
                self.__bool2 = True
                self.__root.title("Untitled - Notepad")
            elif self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END) != "":
                self.__bool2 = False
                self.__root.title("*Untitled - Notepad")
        else:
            file = open(self.__file, "r")

            if self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END) != file.read():
                self.__bool2 = False
                self.__root.title("*" + os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")
            elif self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END) == file.read():
                self.__bool2 = True
                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")

    def __exit(self):
        if self.__file == None:
            if self.__bool2 == False:
                ask = askyesnocancel("Unsaved changes!", "Would you like to save your changes?", icon='warning')
                if ask == None:
                    pass
                elif ask == False:
                    self.__root.destroy()
                    self.event.set()
                elif ask == True:
                    self.__file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                        defaultextension=".txt",
                                        filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                    ("Text Documents", "*.txt"),
                                                    ("JavaScript Documents", "*.js")])

                    self.__bool2 = True

                    if self.__file == "":
                        self.__file = None
                    else:
                        file = open(self.__file, "w")
                        file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
                        file.close()
                        self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__file) + " - Notepad")
                    self.__root.destroy()
                    self.event.set()
        else:
            if self.__bool2 == False:
                ask = askyesnocancel("Unsaved changes!", "Would you like to save your changes?", icon='warning')
                if ask == None:
                    pass
                elif ask == False:
                    self.__root.destroy()
                    self.event.set()
                elif ask == True:
                    file = open(self.__file, "w")
                    file.write(self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END))
                    file.close()
                    self.__root.destroy()
                    self.event.set()

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.__root.mainloop()
        except:
            pass

notepad = Notepad(width=600, height=400)
notepad.run()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E6xy.png)

Comment: What happens if you use `"end-1c"` rather than `END` when getting the contents of the window. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: What does that mean? Did it solve the problem? If so, I can explain why in an answer.

Comment: Yes it does solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the tkinter text widget always adds a trailing newline. When you call `self.__thisTextArea.get(1.0, END)` you are getting all of the text you inserted plus the newline added by tkinter. If you keep saving and then reading the data, each round trip adds an extra newline.

As a general rule, if you want to get out of the text widget precisely what was put in, you need to get all but that trailing newline character. The index `"end-1c"` means "end of the text, minus one character" which effectively gets the actual text that was added to the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in your `def __check(self):`, you compare the opened file with `__thisTextArea`.  A couple questions to consider:

- does `__thisTextArea` have the same formatting that is being used to open the file.  For example: are they both using UTC-8?  If you're not sure, then force them to.
- the opened file may have carriage returns, new line indicators, etc.  That may not be present in `__thisTextArea`.

You didn't say what text you used to test your notepad.  I'd suggest starting with an empty file, then a file with a single character, then a file with a single character and a carriage return.  See what's being inserted into the file that may not have a visible presence in `__thisTextArea`.